# Permission denied when attempting to open ttyS# in GtkTerm

Tags: 14.04, gtk

I'm trying to open a serial port in GtkTerm (downloaded from Ubuntu Software Center), however I'm getting "`Cannot open /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied`" error.

Ubuntu Version: 14.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add yourself to the `dialout` group. It has read/reite permission to that device:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <user>
```

and restart the session.

(`groups` command shows your groups)

Comment: `sudo su <user>` worked without restarting, just export the display after

Answer (score -2):

Use following command:

```
gksu gtkterm
```

Comment: This is probably not advised as you can enable access with the `dialout` group and not have to use/provide `su` rights to users.